# Are Vulkan's RenderPass and Command executed in parallel on the GPU

Tags: render, vulkan

The first question is, I have two renderPasses and I do not set their dependencies, will the two renderPasses be executed in parallel in the GPU or in accordance with the commanbuffer sequence submitted when vkQueueSubmit was executed. For example:

1, renderpass1

2, renderpass2

3, renderpass3

So is gpu going to do 1,2,3 in that order?
or Again, out of order parallel execution 2,1,3?

The second question is, there is only one renderPass, a command buffer, and the command recorded in the command buffer between the vkCmdBeginRenderPass and the vkCmdEndRenderPass is executed in parallel on the GPU or is it executed in the order vkQueueSubmit do. For example, the order of the recorded commands is:

1, vkCmdBindPipeline

2, vkCmdBindDescriptorSets

3, vkCmdDrawIndexed

4, vkCmdBindPipeline

5, vkCmdBindDescriptorSets

6, vkCmdDrawIndexed

So in the GPU we do 1,2,3,4,5,6 sequentially?
or Again, out of order 5,4,1,2,6,3 and doing it in parallel?

Comment: If your case is not mentioned under 6.2 in the [specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2/pdf/vkspec.pdf) then you should not expect a given execution order. PS it is up to the HW if specs do not define order/parallelism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as Vulkan specification is concerned, stuff **without explicit sync** executes *concurrently*. That means serially, in parallel, pre-empted, or any other way the driver wishes. That allows to implement Vulkan on anything, including e.g. singlecore CPUs, and allows any weird-ass optimization the driver might think of.

There are only minimal exceptions to this explicit sync nature of Vulkan. Might as well enumerate them:

1. [Host Write Ordering Guarantees](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-submission-host-writes) — writes through `vkMapMemory` pointer is visible to any subsequent `vkQueueSubmit` work without a pipeline barrier
2. [Rasterization Order](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#primrast-order) — within a single subpass it is not necessary to synchronize color and depth attachment between two `vkCmdDraw*`s
3. obvious stuff — such as that fragment shader sees the output of vertex shader without any explicit sync command. Or that if you use `COHERENT` memory then it is coherent (in the way described by docs).

`vkCmdBind*` commands are only state setting commands. They do not execute anything. They only change the context of subsequent commands. I.e. the `vkCmdDrawIndexed` at 3 executes in the context of Pipeline and Descriptor Sets bound by 1 and 2, and draw 6 executes in context of Pipeline 4 and Descriptor Sets bound by 2 and then modified by 5. The draws at 3 and 6 might execute in any order (or be parallel or pre-empted) with respect to each other.

Per Vulkan principles though the driver is disincentivized to be smart and double-guess you; especially if it would cost resources to check. If you record a `vkCmdDraw*` first, the driver is partial to assume you know what you are doing, and simply start executing that draw first.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! But how does `vkCmdDrawIndexed` at 3 executes make sure that it executed in the context of 1 and 2 , does the cmd1 and cmd2 in the submit cmds argument have to precede vkCmdDrawIndexed cmd?

Comment: @AndLightLight Because `vkCmdBind*` are state commands. They only change the state of the `VkCommandBuffer` object. E.g. `vkCmdBindPipeline` command changes the context of all the commands that are recorded later in the command buffer until `vkCmdEndCommandBuffer()`. How it is actually scheduled is problem for the driver. It has nothing to do with submit on the API level.